# How to encrypt the nuget api key and use it to publish nuget?

Tags: encryption, nexus, nuget-package, visual-studio-2017

Am using Nexus Repository Manager OSS 3.1.0-04. We normally use the below command to push nuget packages.

```
nuget.exe push -Source {NuGet package source URL} -ApiKey key {your_package}.nupkg
```

To secure my API key, I just want to encrypt it and use them in the above commands. to push nuget. Could you please let me know whether it will work or not?

**Modified Command:**

```
 nuget.exe push -Source {NuGet package source URL} -ApiKey EncryptedKey {your_package}.nupkg
```

Comment: Trying to understand why you want to do this. You want to encrypt this key, correct https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference3/nuget.html#_accessing_your_nuget_api_key ? Are you concerned because the key is sent across the network?

Comment: I think what I'm getting at is you would run `nuget setapikey <key> -source <nuget repo url>` and that will encrypt it locally and save it.